# stmt execute array and fetch

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to check if id retrieved from the cookie exist in the database, but this part of the code

```
$stmt->bind_result($id, $uname);
```

and

```
$username = $uname;
```

says undefined variable according to this i should have no problem

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

gives me a warning error in zend. assignment in condition. and I ma not surch if the **stmt->bind_result** is correct for mysqli either.

```
   /**
     * Decode cookies and extract user ID
     */
    $decryptCookieData = base64_decode($_COOKIE['rememberUserCookie']);
    $user_id = explode("UaQteh5i4y3dntstemYODEC", $decryptCookieData);
    $userID = $user_id[1];

    /**
     * check if id retrieved from the cookie exist in the database
     * */
    $db = dbconnect();
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE id = ?');
    $id = $userID;
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
    $id = $userID;
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $uname);

    if ($stmt->fetch()) { 
        $uid = $id;
        $username = $uname;
        /**
         * Create the user session variable
         */
        $_SESSION['id'] = $uid;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $uname;
        $isValid = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `$sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` and check out the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

> Controls how the next row will be returned to the caller. This value must be one of the PDO::FETCH_* constants, defaulting to value of PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE (which defaults to PDO::FETCH_BOTH).

So might be you try to access `$row['id']` from the numeric array:

> PDO::FETCH_BOTH: Return next row as an array indexed by both column name and number
>   Array
>   (
>       [name] => banana
>       [0] => banana
>       [colour] => yellow
>       [1] => yellow
>   )

Comment: im not using PDO but mysqli Prepared stmt